# Is using cross validation on your entire dataset acceptable when dealing with a small sample size

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-modeling, cross-validation

Normally my practice includes using k-folds cross validation on a subset of my dataset and keep a final test set.

When dealing with an exceptionally small dataset, is using cross validation on the entire dataset acceptable?

Comment: You mean k-fold?

Comment: I did, fixed the typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends, there can be different reasons to use CV:

- if you're using it to evaluate your model only, then it's fine to use the whole training set.
- If you're using it to evaluate multiple models and then select the one which performs best (e.g. tuning hyper-parameters), then you shouldn't use the whole training set as you still need to evaluate the result of this tuning step on some unseen data.

Comment: +1. Note too that in the latter case, you could use nested cross-validation to use a small dataset more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

This usually goes this way: you have a train set and a validation set. Both the train and the validation set contain the features, but only the train set contains the target variable.

The train set is then divided in two datasets: train and test, where the train set is used to train the algorithm, and the test set is used to predict new values and compare them to the true values you originally had.

Having said that, it is ok to perform CV on the whole train set. The most extreme of the options is the 'leave one out' method, which trains with the whole train set except just one register, against which the performance is tested. So if you have `n` registers, you could perform `n` CVs.

So yes, it is ok to train an algorithm with the whole train set. But be very careful not to leak data in between!

[Here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html) I leave a link to sklearn docs, where they explain many CV related concepts in great detail with nice plots, which are very useful to understand all this.

Hope this helps!